# Disable innodb support for MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

I currently use MyIasm as my default engine, i ran mysqltuner to check some statistics for my mysql server.

I tried to disable innoDB support with skip-innodb, but this doesn't seem to disable innodb support on my server.

I am using Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41. Everytime i run mysql tuner i keep getting the innodb warning, even after skip-innodb is added in the conf file.

Comment: Paste result of this command: root@mysql> show engines;

Comment: InnoDB      YES   Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys   YES    YES  YES      
MRG_MYISAM  YES  Collection of identical MyISAM tables    NO  NO  NO 
CSV      YES    CSV storage engine             NO  NO NO    
MEMORY   YES Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables    NO  NO  NO   
FEDERATEDNO  Federated MySQL storage engine    NULL NULL NULL    
ARCHIVE YES  Archive storage engine          NO  NO NO  
MyISAM DEFAULT Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance      NO  NO NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show the part of the config file where you put skip-innodb?

Did you put it under the right [section]?

Did you restart the server? Can you `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%INNO%";`

Comment: It seems to be the problem with the section , it was under the myasmcheck section, after i moved it to the upper section of mysql it works now.